# Hive Regex variable length file

Tags: regex, hive

I have a file which is a variable length file but I need to be able to read it in and load it to a staging table. The position of each field is the same in the file, but the ending of it can vary as the last field isn't required.

The length can vary from 805 characters to a max of 822. For the below regex, if I try and load a record that is 805 characters long, it'll null out the whole record. I've tried making the last few fields variable length, but it's still not loading all of the records still.

```
 drop table dz_1318_disc.asc_monthly_stg;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dz_1318_disc.asc_monthly_stg
(
    CMAFFID String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(12)*/',
    ADTMBRCHR String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(97)*/',
    SITENAME String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(90)*/',
    SRVADD1 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVADD2 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVADD3 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVCITY String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    SRVZIP5 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(5)*/',
    SRVZIP4 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(12)*/',
    BILFRST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(50)*/',
    BILLAST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(90)*/',
    BILADD1 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILADD2 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILADD3 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILCITY String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    BILZIP5 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(5)*/',
    BILZIP4 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(12)*/',
    BILPHON String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    SRVPHON String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    NEWCUSTNUM String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(38)*/',
    ACTDATE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(8)*/',
    DISDATE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(8)*/',
    ACTSTAT String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(70)*/',
    RECURR String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    INSTALL String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    LEADSRC String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    CAMKGRUP String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    DISCCODE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(6)*/',
    DISTRIC String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(9)*/ ',
    COMBINE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar (18)*)/'
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
    (
    "input.regex" = "(.{12})(.{97})(.{90})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{3})(.{5})(.{12})(.{50})(.{90})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{3})(.{5})(.{12})(.{10})(.{10})(.{38})(.{8})(.{8})(.{70})(.{10})(.{10})(.{3})(.{3})(.{6})(.{9})(.{9}).*"
    )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/dz/dz_1318/disc.db/kpp_monthly/';
```

The file layout is as follows:

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0----+----1----+----2--
xxxx        012345678                                                                                        JOHNSON, JOHN                                                                             1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216             JOHN                                             JOHNSON                                                                                   1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216            1234567890123456789012345678                              20151024201411101                                                                     479.87999926.7812347899   CMV   450      2        123456789
xxxx        012345678                                                                                        JOHNSON, JOHN                                                                             1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216             JOHN                                             JOHNSON                                                                                   1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216            1234567890123456789012345678                              20151024201411101                                                                     479.87999926.7812347899   CMV   450      25       123456789
xxxx        012345678                                                                                        JOHNSON, JOHN                                                                             1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216             JOHN                                             JOHNSON                                                                                   1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216            1234567890123456789012345678                              20151024201411101                                                                     479.87999926.7812347899   CMV   450      258      123456789
xxxx        012345678                                                                                        JOHNSON, JOHN                                                                             1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216             JOHN                                             JOHNSON                                                                                   1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216            1234567890123456789012345678                              20151024201411101                                                                     479.87999926.7812347899   CMV   450      2
xxxx        012345678                                                                                        JOHNSON, JOHN                                                                             1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216             JOHN                                             JOHNSON                                                                                   1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216            1234567890123456789012345678                              20151024201411101                                                                     479.87999926.7812347899   CMV   450      25
xxxx        012345678                                                                                        JOHNSON, JOHN                                                                             1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216             JOHN                                             JOHNSON                                                                                   1234 WEST STREET              APT B                         ATTN JOHN                     SOME CITY                     TX 78216            1234567890123456789012345678                              20151024201411101                                                                     479.87999926.7812347899   CMV   450      258
```

Comment: it would be useful if you can provide some sample data

Comment: added... Sorry, had to scrub the data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you have to specify a non fixed length for your last columns `(.{0,9})`, additional to that you need to include one more column if you want to see your last element (123456789) in an independent column

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dz_1318_disc.asc_monthly_stg
(
    CMAFFID String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(12)*/',
    ADTMBRCHR String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(97)*/',
    SITENAME String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(90)*/',
    SRVADD1 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVADD2 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVADD3 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVCITY String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    SRVST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    SRVZIP5 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(5)*/',
    SRVZIP4 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(12)*/',
    BILFRST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(50)*/',
    BILLAST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(90)*/',
    BILADD1 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILADD2 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILADD3 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILCITY String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(30)*/',
    BILST String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    BILZIP5 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(5)*/',
    BILZIP4 String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(12)*/',
    BILPHON String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    SRVPHON String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    NEWCUSTNUM String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(38)*/',
    ACTDATE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(8)*/',
    DISDATE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(8)*/',
    ACTSTAT String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(70)*/',
    RECURR String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    INSTALL String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(10)*/',
    LEADSRC String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    CAMKGRUP String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(3)*/',
    DISCCODE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(6)*/',
    DISTRIC String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar(9)*/ ',
    COMBINE String COMMENT '/*@type=varchar (18)*)/',
    YOUREXTRACOLUMN String
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
    (
    "input.regex" = "(.{12})(.{97})(.{90})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{3})(.{5})(.{12})(.{50})(.{90})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{30})(.{3})(.{5})(.{12})(.{10})(.{10})(.{38})(.{8})(.{8})(.{70})(.{10})(.{10})(.{3})(.{3})(.{6})(.{9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9}).*"

    )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
;
```

test it

```
select combine, yourextracolumn,  length(combine) from dz_1318_disc.asc_monthly_stg
```

output

```
2        ,123456789,9
25       ,123456789,9
258      ,123456789,9
3,,1
35,,2
358,,3
```